# How to call an executable jar from php with an argument passed to main method

Tags: java, php, jar, executable-jar

I have created an executable jar and it works fine. For the testing purpose, I have used a dummy variable in the main method.

Instead, I need to pass a string variable, while calling this executable jar from php.

In short, I need to:

1. Call the executable jar from PHP
2. While calling the jar, I need to pass a string variable from PHP to the main method of the class inside executable jar.

How can I accomplish the aforesaid?

Comment: I have never used PHP but does it have mechanism to run installed apps? For example can you run a batch file through PHP if so then you can pass this arguments. java -jar jar-file your_params

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
shell_exec("java -jar your_JAR.jar arg1 arg2");
```

you can also execute Java at all by using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of `shell_execute`, giving it `$output` and & `$return_var` variables (see the linked manual page) and seeing what they contain after the call.