# Sending PHP variable to Java Jar file via shell_exec()

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

I'm trying to convert an Apple PNG file to a normal PNG file. There is a PHP class out there I found that does this, but it only works on some types of Apple PNG files. I have, however, found a Java application that's supposed to convert Apple's PNG files in their, apparently, many varieties.

I'm working in PHP, and I don't know Java at all, which is the biggest problem with me trying to get this to work.

This is the Java application I want to use:

https://github.com/CuelogicTech/Convert-iOS-Application-PNG-images

Below is the stackoverflow question most like this one:

[How to call an executable jar from php with an argument passed to main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766464/how-to-call-an-executable-jar-from-php-with-an-argument-passed-to-main-method)

I was told by someone who knows Java that the Java Jar file I'm referencing accepts the filename as an argument. I installed JRE on my linux server and attempted the following shell command:

```
$command = "java -jar /path/PNGConverter.jar /path/filetoconvert.png";
shell_exec($command);
```

When I put this command in, whether via code or directly into the terminal, nothing happens. (no errors, either). I'm hoping someone can help point at what I'm missing here, thanks for your time.

Comment: as you have newly installed Java, you need to check it's working fine, in termainl type this, `java -v` and tell what you got

Comment: java -v says its an invalid command. java -version returns: "java version 1.7.0_71 (new line) OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora...) (new line) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: I'm assuming it would create the new file in the same folder as the old file? I checked the folder the Jar file is in and don't see it there either

Comment: yes my bad `java -version` is the correct, and yes it will be placed in the same folder as the source image, and will add `-new` to the file name (output file) i have checked the source code, i will try to use that jar file and see if i can help

Comment: Others have tested this on a terminal locally and the jar file does its job. But on our linux server I can't replicate it. I've changed permissions to the image and jar file to 777 just to see if that does anything, but no change. So frustrating!

Comment: i tried it on win8 and same behavior, no errors, no output file! looks like the library is not compatible with all OSs?