# Execute a jar file from a php script

Tags: php, jar, exec, shell-exec

I am new to php and i have a question: Is it possible to start a jar file from php?

Have you ever heard of a way to accomplish?

Thy only way i know is the

```
exec()
```

or

```
shell_exec()
```

function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596237/how-to-run-a-jar-from-a-web-server-using-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766464/how-to-call-an-executable-jar-from-php-with-an-argument-passed-to-main-method ?

Comment: What is missing in `exec()` and `shell_exec()` for your requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec` returns all of the output stream as a string.

[`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

`exec` returns the last line of the output.

[`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

And duplicate of [php shell_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)