# Call a .jar file from JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, java, php

I need to execute a .jar file when the user executes a JS event.

When the user starts the JS event (by clicking on a button), a JS function needs to start a .jar file located in the user's computer.

I have been looking for it, and all the answer that I got point me to use PHP instead of JS in this situation.

Can anyone help me with that?

Is the exec() PHP method the best way to solve the problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Let's hope it's **not possible** otherwise the next page you surf will run lots if bad code on your pc... the closest you could probably get to would be calling a JNLP file starting a WebStart application or applet which then in turn may be allowed to execute local logic

Comment: Is your HTML/JS running of some remote webserver? If so, you aren't going to be able to just load a jar file off the user's computer and execute it. That would be a major security hole.

Comment: PHP runs on server, so you cant launch anyhing on user's computer. As of JavaScript, it doesn't have access to user computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not possible to do this.**

PHP can only run code in your server. You cannot force a client to run a jar file (*unless* they are using an exploited browser).

Answer (score 1):

```
shell_exec("java -jar your_JAR.jar arg1 arg2");
```

I've found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766464/how-to-call-an-executable-jar-from-php-with-an-argument-passed-to-main-method).

Hope it helps!

Comment: That runs the .jar file on the server, not on the client system.