# How to execute a jar file in Xampp through php

Tags: java, php, xampp

I'm trying to call jar file from a php script using XAMPP in windows. Like this

```
    echo shell_exec("java -jar printhello.jar $hello);
```

but it's not printing anything on browser. From XAMPP shell i tried manually

```
    java -jar printhello.jar "hello"
```

, it says the following error 'java' not recognized. But, i have installed jdk on windows. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766464/how-to-call-an-executable-jar-from-php-with-an-argument-passed-to-main-method

Comment: Is your java.exe in the windows path?

Comment: @xander yes java.exe in c:/Program Files/ path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JAVA to Path variable in windows to make it global
this link may help you
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: i've already edited the system variables & ran the same jar file from cmd in windows it works, but in the shell cmd provided by XAMPP it isn't gives 'java' not recognized

Comment: did you restart XAMPP after adding the path

Comment: Yeah I did restart the xampp control panel.

Comment: After restarting the system completely I got it working. Thank you!